# Chi square test error "Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect"

Tags: r, chi-squared

I ran a chi-squared test in R and the results are:

```
crianza = matrix(c(1,1,0,12,12,7,2,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,5,
      0,0,0,1,1,2,0,0,3,0,0,0,13,35,29,0,0,1,10,
      0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0),ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
colnames (crianza) = c("Neonate","Juevenile","Adult")
rownames (crianza) = c("C.acronotus","C.limbatus","C.obscurus","C.perezi",
 "C.porosus","C.falciformis","G.cuvier","G.cirratum","M.canis",
 "R.porosus","R.lalandii","S.lewini","S.mokarran","S.tiburo")    
crianza = as.table(crianza)

Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  crianza
X-squared = NaN, df = 26, p-value = NA

Warning message:
In chisq.test(crianza) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

Does anyone know why it gave a warning? Is it because I am using a wrong method?

Comment: This question is perhaps a better fit for the Cross Validated site - there is a [good existing answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81483/warning-in-r-chi-squared-approximation-may-be-incorrect) there.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/81483/60634, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/155523/60634. If you look at the source for `chisq.test`, that message appears once, after `if (any(E < 5) && is.finite(PARAMETER))`, where `E` might be `n*p` or `outer(sr, sc, "*")/n`, depending on non-matrix or matrix input, respectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting `NA` values because you have rows with no counts at all.

```
cc <- crianza[rowSums(crianza)>0,]
chisq.test(cc)
```

To circumvent the warning, try `simulate.p.value=TRUE`:

```
chisq.test(cc, simulate.p.value=TRUE)
```

Note that this as an extremely unbalanced table, with simulated p-values you will essentially get a value as small as 1/(number of simulations run):

```
chisq.test(cc, simulate.p.value=TRUE, B=1e6)
```

I got as far as `B=1e7` before I ran out of patience. You should probably not worry about reporting values beyond "the p-value is very small, at most 1e-6"

Comment: I ran Chi test on SPSS and the result were so diferent P=0,407

Comment: sorry, I have no idea what SPSS is doing in this case.

Comment: Because the P value is so different than in R (p-value = 0.0004998)

Comment: to figure this out you, or someone else, needs to  (1) you're really using the same data in both cases, nothing funny happened in conversion; (2) see what command and options you used when running the chi-squared test in SPSS.